# Flutter Navigator: Dynamic initial route

Tags: navigation, flutter

My app displays some introduction screens only on the first launch of the app. After the first launch the first screen to display should be my `HomePage`. I tried these routes:

```
"/" -> HomePage()
"/intro" -> IntroPage()
```

and then set the `initialRoute` like that:

```
initialRoute: isFirstLaunch ? "/intro" : "/"
```

With that configuration Flutter first puts the `HomePage()` on the navigation stack and the `IntroPage()` on top, when the `initialRoute` is `"/intro"`. This is bad, because `HomePage()` loads a `CameraPreview`, so it asks for permissions and is resource intensive. It shouldn't be loaded until I navigate to home explicitly.

I also tried this configuration:

```
"/" -> IntroPage()
"/home" -> HomePage()
```

Then I have the `IntroPage()` on by back stack, which is also not what I want.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
"intro": (BuildContext context) => IntroPage()
"home": (BuildContext context) => HomePage()
```

makes sure that both routes are top-level routes without a parent.

Comment: Worked great for me.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! For those who couln't make it work, just make sure you use => not ->. I got my routes defined this way: routes: {
            'main' : (context) => PageStock(),
            'guest' : (context) => SignInPage()
          },

Comment: what do you mean by `top-level routes without a parent`?

Answer (score 11):

The documentation for MaterialApp's [`initialRoute`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/initialRoute.html) property explains this behavior as follows:

> If the route contains slashes, then it is treated as a "deep link",
>   and before this route is pushed, the routes leading to this one are
>   pushed also. For example, if the route was /a/b/c, then the app would
>   start with the three routes /a, /a/b, and /a/b/c loaded, in that
>   order.

Comment: Muchas gracias Sebastian. For my particular condition, this proved to be very insightful... thank you so very much...

Answer (score 6):

How about just load the desired widget directly as your `MaterialApp` app `home` :

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: isFirstLaunch? IntroScreen():HomeScreen(),
    );
```

Comment: what if there are like 3 screens and you want for the three screens to maybe be the initial screen according to condition, i posted a question about this if you could help >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70955476/flutter-multiple-conditions-on-witch-is-going-to-be-home-screen-using-shared-pre