# Flutter multiple conditions on witch is going to be home screen using Shared Prefs

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a login screen, after the user logs in he goes to the Working Screen, if the user is loged in and he leaves the app and comes back i made it so the home screen with be the Working Screen using shared prefs, but now i have another screen witch is the Stop Working Screen, and what im doing is that the user goes to this Working Screen and starts working, when he presses start working on the Working Screen it navigates him to the Stop Working Screen and there is a button to stop working witch will navigate him to the Working Screen. What i need right now is that if the user pressed start working on the Working Screen and left the app i want the home screen to be the Stop Working Screen instead of the Working Screen. So if the user is loged in and he is working(pressed start working button) than i want the Stop Working Screen to be the home screen. Any help would be highly appreciated. Also when the user presses Stop Working and exits the app it should send him to the Working Screen not the Stop Working Screen

```
// Start Working button
                           ElevatedButton(
                              child: loading
                                  ? const Loading()
                                  : const Text(
                                      'Start Working',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                    ),
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: Colors.teal),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                SharedPreferences prefs =
                                    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

// End Work Button

                   ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      putEndWork();
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const WorkingScreen(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'End Work',

// main.dart

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var authorization = prefs.getString('authorization');
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: authorization == null ? const LoginScreen() : const WorkingScreen(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea of BJW's answer should work.

I would expect the part that redeclares `var screenToShow` to cause issues though:

```
  var screenToShow = WorkingScreen();
  if (authorization == null) {
      var screenToShow = LoginScreen();
  } else if (isWorking!) {
      var screenToShow = StopWorkingScreen();
  }
```

Try that same strategy with a helper like:

```
Widget getScreenFromIsWorking([String? isWorking]) {
  if (isWorking != null) {
    return StopWorkingScreen();
  }
  return WorkingScreen();
}
```

Called in main like:

```
var screenToShow = authorization == null ? LoginScreen() : getScreenFromIsWorking(isWorking);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another variable to Shared Prefs, called it for example `isWorking`. `isWorking` is set to `true` when "Start working button" is pressed and it is set to false when "End working button" is pressed.

Your main method should also retrieve the `isWorking` variable inside Shared Prefs.

Then change main method to:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var authorization = prefs.getString('authorization');
  bool? isWorking = prefs.getBool('isWorking');
  var screenToShow = WorkingScreen();
  if (authorization == null) {
      var screenToShow = LoginScreen();
  } else if (isWorking!) {
      var screenToShow = StopWorkingScreen();
  }
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: screenToShow,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: on end work button do i do prefs.remove('isWorking')

Comment: or prefs.setString('isWorking', null)

Comment: prefs.setBool('isWorking', false), you should configure the variable as bool, sorry, copy paste mistake in my answer, will change it

Comment: okay dont worry

Comment: getting errors because when i do screenToShow = WorkingScreen(), it says A value of type 'LoginScreen' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'WorkingScreen'. (Documentation)

Comment: aah, ok, add `var` in front of each `screenToshow =` assignment

Comment: oh that fixed but now getting this error
A negation operand must have a static type of 'bool'. (Documentation)

Comment: on if(!authorization). >> and A nullable expression can't be used as a condition. (Documentation), in isWorking

Comment: aah yes, again sorry. authorization is not a bool, but a string... Changed it in the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241649/discussion-between-bjw-and-ajan).

Comment: ok in >> if(!authorization), do i do if(authorization = false), and else if(working == false), because im getting the error there